# How do I return a string with non-alphabetical using the following code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
string = 'jackk982'
y = 0


def is_alpha(x):
    global y
    for char in x:
        for num in range(97, 123):
            if ord(char) == num:
                y += 1
                x = x[y:]
                return x


print(is_alpha(string))
```

I cant seem to find anything wrong, but the output does not give me 982. How can I fix this?

Comment: does this help? https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit Also, have you tried debugging it?

Comment: is there a way to fix this code without using any of those built-in functions?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. Why should the output be 982?  

in the first for loop you're iterating through your string.  
In the second one you're iterating through the numbers 97 and 123. The first if is comparing your first character with every number from 97 to 123, which corresponds to every letter from a to z. Thus the if is true for 'j' and you're returning the rest of the list

Comment: @Henning i am trying to remove all alphabet until it hits a number, and it shall return the rest of the string starting from that number

Comment: Why are you using a ``global y`` instead of a local one? Are you aware of ``str.isalpha``? Are you aware that ``y`` grows at most by 1 per invocation, and is completely seperate from the count of letters/numbers in the string?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes i am aware that y only execute +1 once, how do i let it continue until ord(char) != num?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi would you mind sending your fixed code below using what you just said?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I don't know what you were trying to do with the two for-loops but the simplest way would be the following:

```
string = 'jackk982'


def get_string(x):
    for a in range(0, len(x)):
        if x[a].isdigit():
            return x[a:]


print(get_string(string))
```

For the string `jackk982`, it returns `982`. For another input `hahahahlol5hf` it returns `5hf`.
The code first checks if one of the characters in the string is a number and if so it returns the rest of the string from that character including the number.

Comment: So it finds the first number in the string and returns the tail of the string from that index onward?

Comment: Ah, it's in the comments... OK